# Android background threading

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask, intentservice

I'm making image processor app. I need to scan the phone for pictures and list them with their number of pixels. So that's gonna be a a large impact on performance and as I understood, I need to make it work on background thread.

So my question is, what is the best approach for this? I understand that IntentService may be the best solution, but I'm not sure how I will implement progress bar with it, and I need to return Picture objects and later update the UI on shuffle button. I'm doing update with Glide library so that's gonna go smooth.

Reading about Asynctasks, I stumbled about comments how it's bad and leads to leaks in memory and should avoid using it. rXJava is too complicated at the moment.
 This is my code:

Main activity:

```
@OnClick(R.id.shuffle)
public void shuffleList() {
    Collections.shuffle(listOfImageFiles);
    recyclerViewAdapter = new PictureRecycleViewAdapter(listOfImageFiles, this);
    recyclerView.swapAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter, false);
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@OnClick(R.id.scan)
public void processImages() {

    //progress bar

    listOfPictures = new ArrayList<>();

    //Gets data from default camera roll directory. Note that some of the phone companies have different file paths. So instead of hardcoding string paths, I used this instead.
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getPath();
    File filePath = new File(path);
    listOfImageFiles = scanPhotos(filePath);

    // async?
    for (File file : listOfImageFiles
            ) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());

        //int is sufficient for most today's pixels. long would be overkill - 4 vs 8 bytes
        int pixels = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth();

        listOfPictures.add(new Picture(file.getPath(), pixels));
    }
}

public List<File> scanPhotos(File directory) {
    List<File> listOfPictures = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files
                ) {
            if (file.isDirectory() && !file.isHidden()) {
                listOfPictures.addAll(scanPhotos(file));
            } else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg") || file.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
                    listOfPictures.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
    }

    return listOfPictures;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### IntentService

`IntentService` is definitely a valid approach. You can use *Broadcasts* to return your result to another component of the app, be it Activity or another Service, for example:

1. Start the `IntentService` - if you need some parameters, place them in the Extras of the service intent.
2. Your `IntentService` runs on the background thread until the computation is finished.
3. Upon finishing, send a broadcast with computation result placed in intent extras.
4. In your activity, register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will listen for your computation result broadcast.
5. Upon getting the broadcast in your `Activity`, retrieve the computation result from intent extras.

You might also implement broadcasts received by your Service for things like cancellation of the computation or updating the parameters.

One of the advantages of `IntentService` is that you can easily integrate it with the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) API to defer execution until certain system conditions are met.

#### Alternatives

- You can use a bus library, such as https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to communicate between `Activity` and `Service`  - the only problem is, EventBus won't work with remote services (running in a separate process).
- Like you've mentioned, using RxJava with **IO** and **computation** schedulers is also a good idea.
- `AsyncTask` is fine as long as you not tie it with a hard reference to an activity - don't implement it as an inner class of Activity and if you want to communicate the result back, do it through a `WeakReference<T>`

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` is fine, you just need to be careful with its implementation.

However, for longer running tasks there are better options. `IntentService` is a good option.

When it comes to a responsive UI when using an `IntentService` you could add two things.

## Notifications

Create an ongoing notification that indicates that your App is working on something. This lets users know that their CPU cycles are being eaten by something in the background and they are less likely(?) to be confused and cranky about their device running slower.

Additionally, it gives your App more of an allowance for staying alive when Android is looking for background Apps to kill to release memory.

## EventBus

You can make UI reporting extremely simple by using an EventBus library. I am personally a fan of [greenbot/EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), but there are others.

### Example

In your `Activity`:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onProgressEvent(ProgressEvent event) {
    mProgressBar.setProgress(event.value);
}
```

In your `IntentService`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ProgressEvent(5000));
```